# ClassCastException on raw functional interface lambda invocation

Tags: java, generics

Consider this example:

```
    Function<String, Integer> function = String::length;
    Function rawFunction = function; // warning: unchecked conversion
    rawFunction.apply(new Object()); // warning: unchecked call
```

The last line will give `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang. Object cannot be cast to class java.lang.String`. This is not a surprise for me, as Function is declared to accept String.

I know that raw types can give ClassCastException, but all examples I saw are about ClassCastException on unchecked call return object not about method arguments: I can find cast added by a compiler in a bytecode for return object but not for arguments.
Where this behavior is specified? What exactly is causing ClassCastException from my example if not an instruction in a bytecode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way generics work with method parameters is via synthetic bridge methods.

For example, for the `Function` interface - whose raw parameter accepts an `Object`, but the non-raw parameter accepts a *whatever*, you have to have a method that accepts the `Object`.

When I decompiled the code above, I got a line in the bytecode:

```
16: invokeinterface #4,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/function/Function.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

so it's actually trying to invoke a method `apply`, which takes an `Object` as the parameter. This method exists on the `Function`, this is the synthetic bridge method.

If you write a `Function` like this:

```
class MyFunction implements Function<String, Integer> {
  @Override public Integer apply(String input) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

and then decompile it, you will find there is another method there:

```
final class MyFunction implements java.util.function.Function<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer> {
  // Default constructor, as you'd expect.
  MyFunction();

  // The apply method as defined above.
  public java.lang.Integer apply(java.lang.String);

  // What's this?!
  public java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object);
}
```

The `public java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object)` method has been added. This is the synthetic bridge method.

Its bytecode looks like:

```
  public java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: checkcast     #2                  // class java/lang/String
       5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method apply:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       8: areturn
```

which is something like:

```
  public Object apply(Object input) {
    return apply((String) input);
  }
```

Hence, the synthetic bridge method just calls the "non-raw" apply method. So, the `ClassCastException` comes from that cast the synthetic bridge method.

Comment: Yes, the bridge method explains ClassCastException. Bridge methods are to keep polymorphism and lambda is a kind of anonymous implementation of an interface.
But I still can't find cast instruction in a bytecode:

`private static java.lang.Integer lambda$main$0(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #62                 // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
       4: invokestatic  #63                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       7: areturn`

Comment: That's because this bytecode isn't the bridge method's bytecode, it's the actual method's bytecode.

Comment: I don't see other related methods in the bytecode using javap -c -p -s -v

Comment: I figured out that bridge methods for lambdas aren't inserted during compilation, they are on responsibility of a VM: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html